# Microsoft Teams: How to get all tabs from a Team's channel?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

In an app I need to access the **[tabs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/index#tabs)** in Microsoft Teams. Is there an API to get titles and tab links of existing tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no API for this yet. It's on our backlog for our Microsoft Graph APIs, but it's not there yet. Unfortunately I don't have a solid ETA for when it will be supported.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Note: there is a UserVoice request that goes in this direction -> https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/31531228-provide-an-api-method-to-get-a-list-of-all-tabs-in

Answer (score -2):

The API was just released, checkout the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channels_tabs_list)
`GET /beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/tabs` should give you access to that kind of result.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "794f0e4e-4d10-4bb5-9079-3a465a629eff",
      "name": "My Contoso Tab - updated",
      "teamsAppId": "06805b9e-77e3-4b93-ac81-525eb87513b8",
      "configuration": {
        "entityId": "2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154",
        "contentUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154/tabView",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154",
        "removeUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154/uninstallTab"
      },
      "sortOrderIndex": 20,
      "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%3ac2e36757ee744c569e70b385e6dd79b6%40thread.skype/tab%3a%3afd736d46-51ed-4c0b-9b23-e67ca354bb24?label=my%20%contoso%to%tab
    },
    {
      "id": "b5d5f001-0471-49a5-aac4-04ef96683be0",
      "name": "My Trello Tab",
      "teamsAppId": "23134c6b-5e4b-439c-8f70-3ded1df20805",
      "configuration": null,
      "sortOrderIndex": 21,
      "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%3ac2e36757ee744c569e70b385e6dd79b6%40thread.skype/tab%3a%3a3709b35c-a0ba-467c-8001-0f66895fb9d3?label=My%20Trello%Tab
    }
  ]
}
```